# Debugging C++ in Eclipse with files with same name

Tags: eclipse, gdb

In my source tree, I have some files with duplicate names.  Not really a problem since they are isolated per platform, i.e. "FileReader.cpp" exists in android/ and linux/ but when building for linux, the android/ directory is never touched.

Now, when debugging within Eclipse (on Linux) Eclipse opens up the wrong file!  Not quite sure how, since it seems that GDB is sending the full pathname.

Any ideas ? I know I can get around this by renaming the file, but I'd rather not.

Comment: GDB will give the path of file which in included. So make sure you are doing right.

Comment: Yep, the path given by GDB is right.  But Eclipse opens the wrong file.  I should probably make an repeatable test case and submit a bug report.  If I rename the file that Eclipse is opening to something else, Eclipse opens the right file.  So there is some internal confusion about the paths in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably worked this out by now :)

The correct answer is here http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/636687/:

> In your Debug Launch Configuration in the Source tab you should remove
>   the Default source lookup path. And then add Absolute path. This will
>   ensure that Eclipse use absolut filenames to set breakpoints.